# Crontab throws error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cron

I've below command in crontab, when I run this command in terminal it works fine but when I run this in crontab am getting the following error

```
  * * * * * cd /home/path/application && RAILS_ENV=development ./bundle exec rake namespacefolder:rake_file
```

Error:

```
bundler: command not found: rake
Install missing gem executables with `bundle install`
```

someone please help.

Comment: What wording might be more clear, than what `bundler` already gave to you? **Install missing gem executables with `bundle install`**.

Answer (score 2):

Cron passes only minimal set of environment variables to your jobs. See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23009/reasons-why-crontab-does-not-work)!

Add -lc option to bash for cron execution to use your login environment and set environment path at the top of your crontab.

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/bin
* * * * * /bin/bash -lc "cd ~/home/path/application && RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake namespacefolder:rake_file"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one if not solved with bundle

```
* * * * * /bin/bash -l -c "cd ~/home/path/application && RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake namespacefolder:rake_file"
```

**/bin/bash**

Specify which program to use for executing the command

**-c**

Read and execute commands from the first non-option argument after processing the options, then exit. Any remaining arguments are assigned to the positional parameters, starting with $0.

**-l**

Make this shell act as if it had been directly invoked by login. When the shell is interactive, this is equivalent to starting a login shell with ‘exec -l bash’. When the shell is not interactive, the login shell startup files will be executed. ‘exec bash -l’ or ‘exec bash --login’ will replace the current shell with a Bash login shell. See Bash Startup Files, for a description of the special behavior of a login shell.

Refer this documentation [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Invoking-Bash)